# Hash of hashes: return hash with a specific subkey

Tags: ruby, arrays, chef-infra, hash

I'm new to Ruby and Chef, and am trying to write a cookbook that remounts the root filesystem with ACL enabled.  Ohai is populating `node['filesystem']` with all the mounted filesystems.  How can I specifically find all the items under `node['filesystem']` where `node['filesystem'][:item]['mount'] == '/'`?

Comment: `node['filesystem'][:item]['mount']` is a single hash element, which either is or isn't a slash. Are you looking for all filesystems where `[:item]['mount']` is `/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Hash#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) method:

```
filtered_nodes = node['filesystem'].select do |key, value|
  key == :item && value['mount'] == '/'
end
```

Comment: There is little point in a `select` loop when `node['filesystem'][:item]['mount']` is a single hash element.

Answer (score 0):

```
root_filesystems = node['filesystem'].select do |k, v|
  node['filesystem'][k]['mount'] == '/'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I've just realised what I think you want. `:item` isn't a hash key, but a placeholder for the keys that you want to enumerate.

This will do that for you

```
selection = node['filesystem'].keys.find_all do |item|
  node['filesystem'][item]['mount'] == '/'
end
```

---

Your question is unclear, but I think `node` may be a hash of filesystems.

This will select all keys of `node` that have an element [:item]['mount'] equal to `/`.

```
selection = node.keys.find_all do |key|
  val = node[key]
  val.key? :item and val[:item]['mount'] == '/'
end
```